# once a canvas has a background image the canvas.toDataURL('png') stops working

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have set the background image of the canvas using:

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(source, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

It is working great but now my

```
canvas.toDataURL('png')
```

stops working.

And also clearing the canvas doesn't clear the background image.
Could you please explain where am going wrong.

The code below works fine until I add a background image.

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {       
   window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png')); 
}
```

Also:

```
canvas.clear();
```

The code doesn't clear the background image.

Comment: Do you get a security error in your console?
If the image is from a different domain canvas.toDataURL() didn't work (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image)
canvas.clear() didn't remove the background image. You can use canvas.setBackgroundImage().

Comment: No there is no error shown in the console. Iam getting a new window opened with base-64 data but the image is not getting displayed.

Comment: Which browser do you use? If you use IE9 it doesn't work (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/172). In chrome it works for me.

Comment: Iam using chrome. It is not working :(.

Comment: I made a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/XuVEh/

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle - now it uses setBackgroundImage and it still works. Did you test it?

Comment: Can you close this question John?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(document.getElementById('img1').src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

document.getElementById('dataurl').addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
});
```